# Reset "called" Count on Sinon Spy

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

How do I reset the "called" count on a Sinon spy before each test?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.spied = sinon.spy(Obj.prototype, 'spiedMethod');
});

afterEach(function() {
  Obj.prototype.spiedMethod.restore();
  this.spied.reset();
});
```

But when I check the call count in a test:

```
it('calls the method once', function() {
  $.publish('event:trigger');
  expect(this.spied).to.have.been.calledOnce;
});
```

...the test fails and reports that the method was called X number of times (once for each previous test that also triggered the same event).

Comment: spiedObject.reset() works for me. maybe the issue is because you do restore?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This question was asked a while back but may still be interesting, especially for people who are new to sinon.

<strike>`this.spied.reset()` is not needed as `Obj.prototype.spiedMethod.restore();` removes the spy.</strike>

**Update 2018-03-22**:

As pointed out in some of the comments below my answer, [stub.reset](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.8/stubs/#stubreset) will do two things:

1. Remove the stub behaviour
2. Remove the stub history (callCount).

According to the [docs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.8/stubs/#stubreset) this behaviour was added in sinon@2.0.0.

**The updated answer to the question would be to use [stub.resetHistory()](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.8/stubs/#stubresethistory)**.

Example from the docs:

```
var stub = sinon.stub();

stub.called // false

stub();

stub.called // true

stub.resetHistory();

stub.called // false
```

**Update:**

- If you just want to **reset the call count**, use `reset`. This keeps the spy.
- To **remove the spy** use `restore`.

When working with sinon you can use the [sinon assertions](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#assertions) for enhanced testing. So instead of writing `expect(this.spied).to.have.been.calledOnce;` one could write:

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(Obj.prototype.spiedMethod);
```

This would work as well with `this.spied`:

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(this.spied);
```

There are a lot of other sinon assertion methods. Next to `calledOnce` there are also `calledTwice`, `calledWith`, `neverCalledWith` and a lot more on [sinon assertions](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#assertions).

Comment: `spiedObject.reset() ` seems a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @dman Now that you mention it, I re-read the question and to reset the call count `reset` is correct, as you may want to keep the spy.

Comment: Warning (?): There is a side effect. When reseting with `stub.reset()` it also resets the `.returns()`. I would have loved to keep the returns and only reset the number of calls. Edit: Use `stub.resetHistory()` to reset only the counters!

Comment: `stub.reset()` also remove `stub.callsFake((args)=>{...})` so `stub.resetHistory()` seems better options for remove just the call count

Comment: I'm sure that `spy.reset()` method is deprecated now. If you want to reset the state of the spy, `spy.resetHistory()` would be better instead of `spy.reset()`.